# problem with SQL statement in high score database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a letter game in java and i need to include a high score function into it. Using Microsoft access database through JDBC.
The table in the database contains the following

```
Table name Easy

fields
Name
Score 
Time
```

In need an SQL statement that displays the top 5 scores in the order highest score and lowest time.
eg.
if there are two players who scored 20 the player with the smaller time should be on top but if there is a player who scored 21, he should be on top regardless of the time.

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you, right?

Comment: You can make an entire game, but don't know how to do a basic select?

Comment: That thought crossed my mind also, however naming the table "Easy" makes me think maybe it's an actual question, like he threw in tables for each difficulty level but he doesn't know enough sql to limit to 5 scores or order by 2 columns.

Comment: Do you really need to store all of the scores ever earned in the game? Rather than deal with the overhead of Access it might be simpler to just keep the top X scores in a file and update the file as needed (and I'm a database guy, so I tend to lean towards DB solutions when they are applicable). If you actually do stuff with the old scores like calculate average scores then that's different.

Answer (score 7):

```
select top 5 
    name,
    score,
    time

from easy

order by score desc, time asc
```

Answer (score 3):

The table is named `Easy`, which seems to indicate that it's for players who play on Easy mode.  I'd recommend adding a column for difficulting and just having one big `HighScores` table.

```
SELECT TOP 5 
  name, score, time
FROM HighScores
WHERE difficulty = 'Easy'
ORDER BY score desc, time asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that you asked, but you might be interested to know that the answer is different with different databases.  For instance, in Oracle that would be

```
select
    name,
    score,
    time
from easy
where rownum <= 5
order by score desc, time asc
```

while in PostgreSQL, it would be

```
select
    name,
    score,
    time
from easy
order by score desc, time asc
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 5 Name
From Easy
order by score desc, time asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Score, Time
FROM Easy
ORDER BY Score DESC, Time
```

Answer (score 0):

Other folks have suggested the `SELECT TOP 5...` solutions, but fwiw, this syntax is nonstandard SQL supported by Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase.  If you use another brand of database, it won't work.  You should be edit your question and specify what brand and version of database you're using, because the answer could be different based on that information.

Comment: The second sentence in the question says "Using Microsoft access database through JDBC."

Comment: Very well!  I added that tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
select top5 Score, Time from Easy order byScore desc, Time
```